# Unsure of best way to handle a task in SQL

Tags: sql

I have items in a table that need to have a history associated with them. The history will have information about where a part is / has been. So, Part A was received, then put in a machine, then taken out, then tested, then put into a new machine.

I need to store each of those events and associate them with the part.

originally my thought was to simply add a column each time a new event happened. so PartA would have a column Hist1 = receivedID, Hist2 = usedID .. and so on. With each column pointing to an ID that identifies the event. But this doesn't feel like a clean solution at all, With parts sometimes moving around a lot, the amount of columns could get unnecessarily big for some, and would be left empty for others.

Would anyone with more experience have an Idea as to how best handle this?

Comment: Create two tables, one for history and other for lookup values for history. The lookup values will have an ID and description of the event/history. The other would consist of the history itself. The mapping would be 1 to 1. If the stages of history increase, you can increase the number of rows in the lookup value table. Hope i helped.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a EVENTS table. In that EVENT row, you will associate the corresponding part with the event itself.

Something like this:

```
create table parts(part_id numeric(10) primary key, ... more parts columns);
create table part_events(
  event_id numeric(10) primary key,
  part_id numeric(10) references parts(part_id),
  event_number numeric(2) not null,
  event_type varchar(24) not null, -- event type
  tstamp timestamp not null, -- date/time of the event
  ...
);
```